# jQuery animation works in Firefox but doesnt work in other browsers

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm working on a slider plugin. It works as it's supposed to in Firefox but in Chrome, IE and Safari instead of moving left the animation goes up and instead of decreasing width it decreases height.
http://htc1swallpapers.zxq.net/jquery.squares.html

HTML and CSS

```
<div id="container"></div>


 #container{
     position:relative;
     width: 854px;
     height: 418px;
     margin: 100px;
     border: 3px solid #333;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 .bar{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     opacity: 0;
 }



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').myplugin({sw: 60, sh: 60, animation: 'vertical'});
//  setTimeout(function(){$('#container').myplugin({sw: 60, sh: 60, animation: 'horizontal'});}, 15000);
});
```

jQuery plugin

```
// JavaScript Document
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({

        myplugin: function(settings){

            var defaults = {
                speed: 200,
                easing: 'fadeout',
                animation: 'vertical',
                sw: 20, //slice width
                sh: 20, //slice height
                images: 1           
            }

            var settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);

            return $(this).each(function(){

                var opt = settings,
                    cont = $(this),
                    width = cont.innerWidth(),
                    height = cont.innerHeight(),
                    arr = [],
                    hc = Math.ceil(width/opt.sw), //horizontal slices count
                    vc = Math.ceil(height/opt.sh); //vertical slices count


                if(opt.animation === 'vertical'){
                    var loaded = false;
                    cont.empty();
                    for(v = 0; v < vc; v++){
                        for(h = 0; h < hc; h++){
                            if(v == 1) cont.append('<div class="bar" id="bar' + h + '"></div>');
                            var slices = {
                                src: '<img class="square" id="slice' + h.toString() + v.toString() + '" src="shred/squares/img1' + v.toString() + h.toString() + '.jpg"/>',
                                x: h * opt.sw, //offset left
                                y: v * opt.sh, //offset top
                                id: h.toString() + v.toString()
                            }
                            arr.push(slices);
                        }

                    }


                    $.each(arr, function(index, value){
                        for(d = 0; d < hc; d++){
                            if(arr[index].x == d * opt.sw){
                                cont.find('#bar' + d).append(arr[index].src);
                                cont.find('#slice' + arr[index].id).css({'top': arr[index].y, 'left': 0});
                            }
                            loaded = (d == hc -1) ? true : false;
                        }
                    });

                    if(loaded){
                        $('.bar').css({'width': opt.sw, 'height': vc * opt.sh, 'overflow': 'hidden', 'top': 0, 'left': width + opt.sh});

                        function slidein(h, del){setTimeout(function(){
                            cont.find('#bar' + h).stop().animate({
                            'left': h * opt.sw, 
                            'opacity': 1}, opt.speed*10)}, del + 2000);
                        }

                        function slideout(h, del){setTimeout(function(){
                            cont.find('div#bar' + h).stop().animate({
                                'width': 0,
                                'opacity': 0}, opt.speed*6)}, 10000 - h * 100);
                        }

                        for(h = 0; h < hc; h++){
                            var del = h * opt.speed;
                            slidein(h, del);
                            slideout(h, del);
                        }
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `loaded` outside of the each loop never gets called. I can get it to work in chrome if I modify the code like this:

```
$.each(arr, function(index, value){
    for(d = 0; d < hc; d++){
        if(arr[index].x == d * opt.sw){
            cont.find('#bar' + d).append(arr[index].src);
            cont.find('#slice' + arr[index].id).css({'top': arr[index].y, 'left': 0});
        }
        loaded = (d == hc -1) ? true : false;

        if(loaded){
            $('.bar').css({'width': opt.sw, 'height': vc * opt.sh, 'overflow': 'hidden', 'top': 0, 'left': width + opt.sh});

            function slidein(h, del){setTimeout(function(){
                cont.find('#bar' + h).stop().animate({
                'left': h * opt.sw, 
                'opacity': 1}, opt.speed*10)}, del + 2000);
            }

            function slideout(h, del){setTimeout(function(){
                cont.find('div#bar' + h).stop().animate({
                    'width': 0,
                    'opacity': 0}, opt.speed*6)}, 10000 - h * 100);
            }

            for(h = 0; h < hc; h++){
                var del = h * opt.speed;
                slidein(h, del);
                slideout(h, del);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it works but it create another problem, placing the (if(loaded) functions) inside ($.each function) will cause the if(loaded) functions to repeat for each element in the array hence slowing the animation and creating conflics. but thanks for pointing it out, now i know where the problem is